# htaccess not get index file after rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `htaccess` is this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)?$ show.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So whenever browser get 'any thing' after `root folder` then it will go show.php and parameter will be  'any thing' . 
Note: it will not effect if it have extension or a folder.

But there is index file in my root folder. So browser should take index file first. So that, i added this in `.htaccess` file :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

But not working. So is there anything to do, to show at least index file whenever root folder visited ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your .htaccess like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ /show.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: thanks. But it's not working with trailing slash in front of show.php file. But when i remove slash it is working. Don't know why.
Your answer is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I made trailing slash optional in my rule now.